# Сериализация двумерного массива в JS

Tags: javascript, json

Пытаюсь сериализовать двумерный массив в JS.

Почему в следующем случае сериализация не выполняется?

```
var arr = [];
arr[0] = [];
arr[0]["prop1"] = 'test';
arr[0]["prop2"] = 'test';

arr[1] = [];
arr[1]["prop1"] = 'test';
arr[1]["prop2"] = 'test';

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr)); // [[], []]
```

А а так работает.

```
var arr = [];
arr[0] = {};
arr[0].prop1 = 'test';
arr[0].prop2 = 'test';

arr[1] = {};
arr[1].prop1 = 'test';
arr[1].prop2 = 'test';
```

Как мне сериализовать массив из первого варианта?

Comment: 1. Потому что массив сериализуется перечислением своих элементов, а объект - перечислением своих свойств. 2. `arr[0][1] = 'test'; arr[0][2] = 'test';`

Comment: @Igor, тогда как можно сериализовать массив массивов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Потому что массив сериализуется перечислением своих элементов, а объект - перечислением своих свойств.

2.

```
var arr = [];
arr[0] = [];
arr[0][1] = 'test';
arr[0][2] = 'test';

arr[1] = [];
arr[1][1] = 'test';
arr[1][2] = 'test';

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr)); //[[null, 'test', 'test'], [null, 'test', 'test']]
```